# Converting raw string to string in rust

Tags: json, rust, serde

I'm decoding raw bytes with `base64::decode` and getting something like `"{\"foo\":1,\"bar\":\"first\"}"`. However, serde_json wants a string like `{"foo":1,"bar":"first"}`

So I need to convert

```
let raw = r#""{\"foo\":1,\"bar\":\"first\"}""#.to_string();
```

into

```
let converted = "{\"foo\":1,\"bar\":\"first\"}".to_string();
```

Actually this is working :

```
fn format_string(inp : &str) -> String {
    let temp = inp.to_string().replace("\\\"", "\"");
    if temp.len() < 3 {
        return temp
    }
    temp[1..temp.len()-1].to_string()
}
```

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Your "raw" string looks like a JSON string, so you should be able to deserialize it twice – The first time into a `String`, and the second time into your final data structure.

Comment: Yep, double deserializing is working, thank you!

Comment: Where does the base 64 data come from? It might make more sense to fix its creation so that it contains the JSON data directly instead of being JSON-encoded twice.

Comment: I'm not sure double deserializing is better

Answer (score -1):

You only need to deserialize it once:

```rust
let deserialized: String = serde_json::from_str(&raw).unwrap();

assert_eq!(deserialized, converted)
```

Try it in [this rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ebf3ae0ef476a85f7772962f7d8b6b04)

Here is why:

```
let raw = r#""{\"foo\":1,\"bar\":\"first\"}""#.to_string();
```

`raw` represents string `"{\"foo\":1,\"bar\":\"first\"}"` , which is a valid JSON. It represents a JSON string instead of a JSON object.
It can be deserialized to a string whose content is  `{"foo":1,"bar":"first"}`.